# How to call a superview's touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event method?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitouch, uiresponder

I created a `UIView` subview which I add to my `UIViewController` in storyboard, I want to respond to a tap on the subview and call the superview's implementation of the following method. The call works properly, but it doesn't pass as an argument the proper `touch.tapcount` to the superview's implementation.

Here is the method in the subview:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self]anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];

    if(touch.tapCount == 2){

        [self.superview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    }
}
```

Here is the method in the superview, the if block is not executed:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self]anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];

    if(touch.tapCount == 2){

      //Code is not executed here
    }
}
```

**Solution**

change this statement in superview:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self]anyObject];
```

to this:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1]] anyObject];
```

Comment: In the superview, have you verified that `touch` is not `nil`?

Comment: Yes, touch is nil in the superview.

Comment: `anyObject` may return *any object*. There's a clue in the name. So there's no reason to suppose the two `touch`es are the same touch, even if `touchesForView:` were returning the same set, which it seemingly isn't.

Comment: @Nikita It's `nil` because the touch isn't for the superview so calling `[event touchesForView:self]` in the superview gives you no results.